# Java Receiving attachment mail error

Tags: java, email, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, mime

I have a java code to get attachment using java mail and i'm able to download the attachment and inserting into specific folder. But the problem is when i'm sending email with attachment from Blackberry phone i get  error as follows for downloading the attachment.

```
ERROR [STDERR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\CCjboss\server\sor
emicc\deploy\eis.ear\CC.war\attachment\=?utf-8?B?MS5qcGc= (The filename, directo
ry name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
07:31:10,739 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
07:31:10,741 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStr
eam.java:179)
07:31:10,744 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStr
eam.java:131)
07:31:10,747 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.infosense.eis.webapp.util.Mobilekiran.sav
eFile(Mobilekiran.java:230)
07:31:10,750 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.infosense.eis.webapp.util.Mobilekiran.Mob
ileTimeCheckTask(Mobilekiran.java:179)
07:31:10,753 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.infosense.eis.webapp.util.Mobilekiran.run
(Mobilekiran.java:38)
07:31:10,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:432
)
07:31:10,759 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:382)
```

I think its with some encoding and decoding problem. Attachment get encoded or something

```
=?utf-8?B?MS5qcGc=
```

The below is the code to receive a email with attachment

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
/**
 *
 * @author  Administrator
 */
public class Mobilekiran extends TimerTask{
     List emattach=new ArrayList();
  List emails = new ArrayList();
  List attachments=new ArrayList();
  String emailbody=null;
  String bodypart=null;
  String s1=null;
  String fromaddress=null;
  String subject=null;
  String body=null;
  String date1=null;
  String filename=null;
  int filesize=0;

    public void run() {
        MobileTimeCheckTask(); 
    }

    private void MobileTimeCheckTask(){

    String host = "mail.**********.com";
    String username = "*****@****.com";
    String password = "*******";
    String downloadDir = "E:/CCjboss/server/soremicc/deploy/eis.ear/CC.war/attachment";
    String provider = "pop3";
        try{

             // Create empty properties
  Properties props = new Properties();

  // Get the session
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

  // Get the store
  Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
  store.connect(host, username, password);

  // Get folder
  Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);


  Message messages[] = folder.getMessages();
   for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {


    // from 
       Address[] toaddress1=messages[i].getAllRecipients();
      String toaddress=toaddress1[0].toString();
       System.out.println("to address"+toaddress1[0].toString());

    emails.add(0,messages[i].getFrom()[0].toString());
    s1=messages[i].getFrom()[0].toString();
    InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress(s1);
     fromaddress=address.getAddress();

    // subject
    emails.add(1,messages[i].getSubject());
    subject=messages[i].getSubject();
    // received date
    if (messages[i].getReceivedDate() != null) {
     emails.add(2,messages[i].getReceivedDate().toString());
     date1=messages[i].getReceivedDate().toString();
      // emattach.add(0,emails);
    } else {
     emails.add(2,new Date());
     date1=(new Date()).toString();
      // emattach.add(0,emails);
    }

    // body and attachments
    //email.body = "";
    Object content = messages[i].getContent();
    if (content instanceof java.lang.String) {

     emails.add(3,(String) content);

    } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {

     Multipart mp = (Multipart) content;
     boolean d=true;
     for (int j = 0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {

      Part part = mp.getBodyPart(j);
      BodyPart bp=mp.getBodyPart(j);
      Object o2 = bp.getContent();
      if (o2 instanceof String) {

                            System.out.println("**This is a String BodyPart**");
                            System.out.println("bodypart "+(String)o2);
                            if(d)

                            emails.add(3,(String)o2);
                            body=(String)o2;
                            d=false;

                        } 

      String disposition = part.getDisposition();

      if (disposition == null) {

       MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) part;
       if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        // Plain

        emailbody += (String) mbp.getContent();
           emails.add(3,emailbody);

       } 

      } else if ((disposition != null) && (disposition.equals(Part.ATTACHMENT) || disposition .equals(Part.INLINE))) {

       // Check if plain
       MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) part;
       if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {

           emailbody += (String) mbp.getContent();
           emails.add(3,emailbody);

       } else {
        //EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();

           System.out.println("the filename  i required"+part.getFileName().toString());


        attachments.add(0,Mobilekiran.decodeName(part.getFileName()));
         filename=decodeName(part.getFileName());
        File savedir = new File(downloadDir);
        savedir.mkdirs();
        // File savefile = File.createTempFile( "emailattach", ".atch", savedir);
        File savefile = new File(downloadDir,attachments.get(0).toString());
        attachments.add(1,savefile.getAbsolutePath());
        attachments.add(2,new Integer(Mobilekiran.saveFile(savefile, part)));
        filesize=saveFile(savefile,part);
        emattach.add(0,attachments);
       }
      }
     } // end of multipart for loop 
    emattach.add(0,emails);
   System.out.println(emattach);
   emattach.clear();
   System.out.println(emattach);
    messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED , true);

      } // end messages for loop



    // Finally delete the message from the server.

   }

   // Close connection
   folder.close(true); // true tells the mail server to expunge deleted messages
   store.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }  
    private static String decodeName(String name) throws Exception {
  if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
   return "unknown";
  }
  String ret = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");

  // also check for a few other things in the string:
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=\\?utf-8\\?q\\?", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("\\?=", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=20", " ");

  return ret;
 }

 private static int saveFile(File saveFile, Part part) throws Exception {

  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream(saveFile));

  byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
  InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
  int ret = 0, count = 0;
  while ((ret = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
   bos.write(buff, 0, ret);
   count += ret;
  }
  bos.close();
  is.close();
  return count;
 }
}
```

Please help me out in solving the above problem.

Comment: The string `=?utf-8?B?MS5qcGc=` is the mime / base64 encoded version of "1.jpg". I would have thought that javamail decodes this automatically when using `getFileName`.

Comment: It doesn't, here's why: (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#encodefilename)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the attachment is encoded.

Comment: For Decoding we are using                                     private static String decodeName(String name) throws Exception {
  if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
   return "unknown";
  }
  String ret = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");

  // also check for a few other things in the string:
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=\\?utf-8\\?q\\?", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("\\?=", "");
  ret = ret.replaceAll("=20", " ");

  return ret;
 }

Comment: This is UTF-8 decoding. The message is encoded with public key as mentioned in your question. You cannot read them without the private key. As far as I know RIM encrypts all messages before mailing. Same reason RIM's services were suspended in India for sometime.